# Tailwind CSS does not work in React project

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a web application that was built with React.
I didn't use any CSS framework, all styles are written in raw CSS.
I want to integrate Tailwind CSS into this existing project.
I just followed the exact steps here.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

The app runs without any issues, but tailwind Classes are not applied.
Are there any other configuration steps besides that?

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of your style files compiled by tailwind?

Answer (score 1):

please make sure your 'react-scripts' version is higher than v5.0. Tailwind CSS does not recommend using React Create App. However, if you already have an old project, your React app version might be outdated. I'm not quite sure what your real issue is, but this could help you based on my previous experience.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try these solutions.

0. Check the require imports and file paths carefully.
1. Use this tailwindcss link: [create-react-app](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)
2. Just close the editor and restart it. If the problem is still there then follow third step.
3. Make sure you have `index.css` and `tailwind.config.js` file

Make sure the following line is in your `tailwind.config.js`:

```
["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./index.html"],
```

index.css:

[image: index.css file]

taiwind.config.js:

[image: taiwind.config.js]